# Omitting the initial transition/animation

Tags: d3.js, c3

Is it possible to omit the animation at the beginning of the graph generation? I know there is `transition { duration: 0 }`, but I would like to still have other modification transitions.

Can someone help me, please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the right answer from C3.js forum:

```
    var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 100, 200, 150, 300, 200],
            ['data2', 400, 500, 250, 700, 300], ]
    },
    transition: {
        duration: 0
    }
});
chart.internal.loadConfig({
    transition: {
        duration: 500
    }
});
```